# How Spotify android app saves the current music plying time? Like when you exit the app an open it other day?

Tags: android, database, spotify

So I wonder how the android app of spotify saves the current time of playing music in it's local database? It can't be possible to update every second of music
So when you close the app during the music plays, and then you open it (even offline), it shows which music that you were listening and the exact time of remaining of it.
Saving in SharedPrefs?

Comment: This is very easy to implement through the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)[ alternative: [androidx.preference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings)]

Comment: Spotify uses Shared Preferences. It stores the duration of the song, the song name, song artist etc in it

Comment: refer this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1):

It can store the data in Room (SQLite) database or SharedPreferences in onStop or onDestroy lifecycle of the Activity. It can also be tied to the lifecycle of the whole application.

Comment: It can be like this but it shows on other device of yours, when the song is playing on the other device. Like it's synced every second with server.

Comment: In that case it can just send the data to server only when the music starts playing and when it pauses/stops. If you have those values the duration can be imitated.